# IF Statement in a Class formula

Tags: apex

Does anyone know if it's possible to use an "IF" condition within a calculation in an Apex Class?  For example, I have a formula as follows:

```
IF(oli1.Discount__c == NULL){
  oli1.UnitPrice = oli1.Amount__c * opp1.Term__c / 12 * opp1.Term_Factor__c;
}
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
IF(oli1.Discount__c == NULL){
  oli1.UnitPrice = oli1.Amount__c * opp1.Term__c / 12 * 
  IF(opp1.Term_Factor__c == NULL THEN 1 OTHERWISE opp1/Term_Factor__c;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Option 1 (more compact):

```
IF (oli1.Discount__c == NULL) {
  oli1.UnitPrice = oli1.Amount__c * opp1.Term__c / 12 * ((opp1.Term_Factor__c == NULL) ? 1 : opp1.Term_Factor__c);
}
```

Option 2 (more readable):

```
IF (oli1.Discount__c == NULL) {
  Decimal term_factor = (opp1.Term_Factor__c == NULL) ? 1 : opp1.Term_Factor__c;
  oli1.UnitPrice = oli1.Amount__c * opp1.Term__c / 12 * term_factor;
}
```

This is a way to do very simple/quick if statements:

```
(boolean_check) ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

Comment: IMHO it will be MUCH easier to read if you cache the value. `Decimal conditionalValue = boolean_check ? value_if_true: value_if false;` Then merge in `conditionalValue` to the arithmetic operation.

Comment: I would absolutely agree with you as far as readability goes, I'll update my answer to show both options

Comment: This is generically referred to as a `ternary` operation, in case you want to do more research.